# android - onRequestPermissionsResult - does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: android, download, permissions

I'm trying to implement Marshmallow's permission support in MyAdapter class for mylistView, but the method `onRequestPermissionsResult` does not override or implement a method from a supertype ... while I tried the code of Marshmallow's permission for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` to download file from internet in another project it was working well without this error "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"

I'm using an Nexus 5X emulator running Android 8.1.0, API 27.

**MyAdapter Class**

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
        String fileName;
        String dirPath;

        Context context;
        ArrayList<StoryModel> TitleAndImage ;
        ArrayList<StoryModel> forShowEachStoryInNewActivity ;
        LayoutInflater inflter;

        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<StoryModel> TitleAndImage ,ArrayList<StoryModel> forShowEachStoryInNewActivity) {
            this.context = context;
            this.TitleAndImage = TitleAndImage;
            this.forShowEachStoryInNewActivity=forShowEachStoryInNewActivity;
            inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(context));
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return TitleAndImage.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            convertView = inflter.inflate(R.layout.item_story, null);

            TextView t1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ImageView m1= convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            Button b1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttn_bwonload);

            t1.setText(TitleAndImage.get(position).getTitle());
            Picasso.get().load(TitleAndImage.get(position).getImage()).resize(200,200).into(m1);



//TODO : going to Show each story in new Activity

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, ForEachStory.class);

                    String title = forShowEachStoryInNewActivity.get(position).getTitle();
//                  String image = forShowEachStoryInNewActivity.get(position).getImage();
                    String body = forShowEachStoryInNewActivity.get(position).getBody();

                    intent.putExtra("title", title);
//                  intent.putExtra("image", image);
                    intent.putExtra("body", body);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });








//TODO download this story when i click on it's download button

            b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    dirPath   = com.example.abdullah.newstroynory.Utils.getRootDirPath(context);

                    String title_For_Download = forShowEachStoryInNewActivity.get(position).getTitle();
                    fileName = title_For_Download + ".mp3";
                    String audio_For_Download = forShowEachStoryInNewActivity.get(position).getAudio();
//                    String url = audio_For_Download;


//TODO  Marshmallow's permission
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
                    {
                        if (checkPermission())
                        {
                            // Code for above or equal 23 API Oriented Device
                            // Your Permission granted already .Do next code

                             dorDownloadMyAudios (  fileName,  dirPath ,  audio_For_Download);

                        } else {
                            requestPermission(); // Code for permission
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Code for Below 23 API Oriented Device
                        // Do next code

//                        dorDownloadMyAudios (  fileName,  dirPath ,  audio_For_Download);
                    }


                }
            });

            return convertView;

        }






//TODO code of chick of download from the internet into the SD card

    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    private void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText( context, "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store files. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .");
                } else {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
                }
                break;
        }
    }







//TODO  library of downloading file


    private void dorDownloadMyAudios ( String  fileName,  String dirPath , String url){

        PRDownloader.initialize(context);
        PRDownloaderConfig config = PRDownloaderConfig.newBuilder()
                .setDatabaseEnabled(true)
                .build();
        PRDownloader.initialize(context, config);



        int downloadId = PRDownloader.download(url, dirPath, fileName)
                .build()
                .setOnStartOrResumeListener(new OnStartOrResumeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStartOrResume() {

                    }
                })
                .setOnPauseListener(new OnPauseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPause() {

                    }
                })
                .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }
                })
                .setOnProgressListener(new com.downloader.OnProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(Progress progress) {

                    }
                })
                .start(new OnDownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDownloadComplete() {

//                        Log.d("--------->", "onCreate: "+dirPath+fileName);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Hi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.d("------->", "onDownloadComplete: OK ------->");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Error error) {

                    }

                });

    }




}
```

this another project it work well, download audio file without any error

**MainActivity Class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    String fileName;
    String dirPath;



    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/storynory-1e523.appspot.com/o/audio%2Fcroesus-solon-storynory.mp3?alt=media&token=3f4b9ff4-8891-4b8d-9ddf-1d461faf80c2";
        dirPath    = com.example.abdullah.dwonloadaudio.Utils.getRootDirPath(getApplicationContext());
        fileName   = "myPhoto2.mp3";




        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
        {
            if (checkPermission())
            {
                // Code for above or equal 23 API Oriented Device
                // Your Permission granted already .Do next code
                dorDownloadMyAudios (  fileName,  dirPath ,  url);
            } else {
                requestPermission(); // Code for permission
            }
        }
        else
        {

            // Code for Below 23 API Oriented Device
            // Do next code
        }


    }




    private boolean checkPermission() {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Write External Storage permission allows us to do store files. Please allow this permission in App Settings.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Granted, Now you can use local drive .");
                } else {
                    Log.e("value", "Permission Denied, You cannot use local drive .");
                }
                break;
        }
    }







    private void dorDownloadMyAudios (String  fileName, String dirPath , String url){

        PRDownloader.initialize(this);
        PRDownloaderConfig config = PRDownloaderConfig.newBuilder()
                .setDatabaseEnabled(true)
                .build();
        PRDownloader.initialize(getApplicationContext(), config);



        int downloadId = PRDownloader.download(url, dirPath, fileName)
                .build()
                .setOnStartOrResumeListener(new OnStartOrResumeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onStartOrResume() {

                    }
                })
                .setOnPauseListener(new OnPauseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPause() {

                    }
                })
                .setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {

                    }
                })
                .setOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(Progress progress) {

                    }
                })
                .start(new OnDownloadListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDownloadComplete() {

                        Log.d("------->", "onDownloadComplete: OK ");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Error error) {

                    }

                });

    }







  }
```

> note:the code is work before and after all override became deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You can only override the `onRequestPermissionsResult` in a class that extends `Activity` or `AppCompatActivity`. More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])).

Comment: there's a solution For my case ? because i have button in each item of myListView to download !

Comment: Maybe register a `Broadcast receiver` in MyListView, and send an intent from `onRequestPermissionsResult` when you get the required result and receive it in MyListView.